# Choosing the largest number within the column if the first column is equal to other lines

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, numbers, multiple-columns

I want to the program read the column 1, and if the number repeats, look for the column 5 which value is higher

```
1_248637391 .   C   T   592.4
1_248637391 .   C   T   505.79
1_248637400 .   C   A   600.00
1_248756167 rs61732484  C   G   1243.19
1_248756167 rs61732484  C   G   2002.61
```

Output:

```
1_248637391 .   C   T   592.4
1_248637400 .   C   A   600.00
1_248756167 rs61732484  C   G   2002.61
```

I'm working with big dataset, if someone known how to solve it by bash it would be awesome! Thank you soo much for the attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sort` and `awk`:

```
sort -k1,1 -k5,5nr file | awk '!seen[$1]++'
```

`sort` is used to sort the file by column 1 ascending and column 5 numeric descending. `awk` just prints first entry for each value in `column 1`.

**Output:**

```
1_248637391 .   C   T   592.4
1_248637400 .   C   A   600.00
1_248756167 rs61732484  C   G   2002.61
```

Comment: Thank you @Anubhava! 

Can you explain better to me the function of '!seen[$1]++' ?

Comment: `!seen[$1]++` uses an array `seen` with key as `$1`. When `$1` doesn't exist in `seen` then it is incremented using `++` to value as `1` and row gets printed. When same `$1` exists in `seen` then `!seen[$1]` fails the condition and rows don't print.

Answer (score 1):

alternative just with sort

```
$ sort -k5nr file | sort -u -k1,1

1_248637391 .   C   T   592.4
1_248637400 .   C   A   600.00
1_248756167 rs61732484  C   G   2002.61
```

sort descending based on 5th field, resort by field 1 and pick the first element (which is largest based on the first sort, may need `-s` flag)